# Type or namespace 'Map' does not exist in the namespace 'Bing.Maps'

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I added Bing.Maps to my references and it seems to find the xmlns, but it doesn't find it content. I also made everything x86 ( tried ARM too ), but it doesn't find the Map.

[image]
What can I do now? Yes I already restarted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bing Maps SDK you are using is for Windows 8.1 not Windows Phone 8.1. For Windows Phone 8.1 Bing Maps is built into the WP SDK. Here is some info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642089.aspx